# Cronjob not executing

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I am fairly new to crons and how to set them up correctly.

I have a php script that needs to be executed every 20 minutes.

I have setup a cron task with the following settings:

```
Minute * = 0,20,40
Hour * = *
Day of the month * = *
Month * = *
Day of the week * = *
Command * = wget -q -O /dev/null http://websiteaddress.com/wp-content/plugins/xxx/cronjob.php
```

The script uses curl and drags in some information from an external website with json.

I can get this working when going to the web page in the browser but cant get it to work using a cron job...

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is an image to show what my setup is like:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please post the exact notation in your crontab. The above certainly is something different.

Comment: @arkascha that is exact, apart from the web address which I personally do not want to give live for everyone to see

Comment: I am confused, but apparently there indeed do exist some extensions to the simply cron that allow some "expanded" notation. Never seen that in use and the above example looks syntactically invalid to me. But as said: I have no experience with that notation, sorry. Apart from that: have a try using the absolute path to your `wget` executable. Your PATH environment variable might be empty during cron execution, depending on which crontab you use.

Comment: Ah, so you are using some frontend and the above is _not_ your crontab entry, as you claimed. Anyways: you tested with the absolute path to `wget`?

Comment: @arkascha I have tried "wget -q -O /dev/null /httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/xxx/cronjob.php" and waiting on the results of "wget -q -O /dev/null /var/www/vhosts/websiteaddress.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/xxx/cronjob.php" which will be available in about 15 minutes

Comment: What? No! Not the absolute path to the php script you want to execute. `wget` has to use http access. I referred to the path to the `wget` utility the job might not be able to resolve. So something like `/usr/bin/wget`, depending on your system.

Comment: @arkascha sorry, as said I have no experience in cron jobs so when you said absolute I assumed you meant to the executed script... Waiting for results from the absolute wget path

Comment: @arkascha it does not work

Comment: And "it does not work" means what exactly?

Comment: I have the impression that this is not actually your system, but that you try to access some hosted space via some frontend. In that case I suggest you address the support of that hosting serve, they should know what's up.

Comment: @arkascha nothing happens, it does not execute the script

Comment: @arkascha this is my own dedicated server, I use a frontend from plesk because it is easier

Comment: Sorry, but apparently it is not easier, since you don't know what is happening. A typical issue with these frontends: you try around in the dark, not knowing what you actually do. Use a normal crontab entry and you know what is happening. Monitor the system log to see error messages. The more layers you put between you and what you actually want to work with, the less good your connection is.